# Using request scoped beans inside WebClient filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

The use case I have is a request scoped bean for storing cookies, so that they can be propagated later on. With the asynchronous nature of the `WebClient` the requests are executed on different threads, therefore things associated with the thread like the `MDC` for logging. I assume that request scoped beans are handled in a similar manner and are therefore not accessible in a filter.

According to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-context) you can inject/attach objects to the request so that it becomes available in the filter. I tried it though the `attribute` which I got working, but somehow the approach with the `context` does nothing.

Here is the definition of the `WebClient`:

```
@Bean
public WebClient getWebClient(WebClientFilterFactory filterFactory)
{
    ClientHttpConnector connector = new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(httpClient(100, 10));

    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8081")
            .clientConnector(connector)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .defaultRequest(spec -> {
                spec.attribute("AnotherBean", "bar");
            })
            .filter((request, next) -> {
                Optional<Object> value = request.attribute("RequestScopedBean");
               if (value.isPresent()) {
                   log.info("Retrieved from context: {}", value.get());
               } else {
                   log.warn("Found nothing in context!");
               }
               value = request.attribute("AnotherBean");
                if (value.isPresent()) {
                    log.info("Retrieved from context: {}", value.get());
                } else {
                    log.warn("Found nothing in context!");
                }
                Mono.deferContextual(context -> {
                    String bean = context.get("InitialScopedBean");
                    log.info("Retrieved bean from context: {}", bean);
                    return Mono.empty();
                });
               return next.exchange(request);
            })
            .build();
}
```

And this is how it is called:

```
webClient.get()
  .uri("/hello")
  .attribute("RequestScopedBean", "foo")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(HelloWorld.class)
  .contextWrite(context -> context.put("InitialScopedBean", "baz"))
  .block();
```

I only get the log output for the values `foo` and `bar` which are both defined through attribute either as part of the request definition in the builder, or when executing the request. The `baz` from the context is missing and debugging confirms that the `Mono.deferContextual` function is never executed.

As is the case with request scoped beans, I cannot attach them to the request definition on the builder, as that would defeat the purpose of the scope. While I can solve the problem with attributes, I would like to understand what I am doing wrong with the context approach.